# Why is a default ctor needed for this inner (nested) struct?

Tags: c++

I am trying to compile code similar to the snippet below:

```
class System
{
private:
   struct Configuration
   {
      Configuration(/*params*/);
      Configuration(const Configuration&);
      Configuration& operator=(const Configuration&);
      ~Configuration();

      /* member variables */
   } m_config;

   explicit System(const Configuration& cfg);

   // Non copyable constructable, non assignable
   System(const System&);
   System& operator= (const System&);

public:
    System();
    ~System();  
}


//Implementation
System::System()
{
   m_config = Configuration(/*default params*/);
   // ....
}
```

Compiler error: **no matching function for call to ‘System::Configuration::Configuration()’**

When I provide (even merely a declaration not a definition of) a default constructor for the nested struct, the error dissapears - WHY?!

Misc Details:
gcc version 4.4.3 (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5)

Comment: Where are you using the `Configuration` object ?

Comment: +1 for trying to give us just enough code to see your problem, but -1 for stopping short of giving us a real use case for reproducing the error itself. :)

Comment: GMan: Sorry, I realized the shortcoming and edited the snippet, just about the same time you were posting your comment ;)

Comment: Alright, +1 for a well-written question. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

m_config is first default constructed and then assigned.  Use the member list to set its value directly.

```
System::System()
  : m_config(/*default params*/)
{}
```

Comment: Exactly. In other words, the code in the constructor body is *not* initialization, but assignment; but since everything must be initialized prior to entering the body, the compiler will try to default construct it, and fail. One should always use the initialization list to initialize!

Comment: Eeek!. I'm afraid my code snippet led you astray. I cannot use m_config in an initialization list, because there is some work involved in obtaining the default parameters (I have to execute a few lines of code). However, your explanation about first being default constructed then assigned helps explain the issue. Ditto, thanks to you as well GMan.

Comment: However, like I said the error goes away if I merely DECLARE the dflt ctor (and not define it). I would have thought that there would be a link error if there was no definition - or does the compiler autogenerate the dflt ctor code behind the scenes?

Comment: Add a constructor to Configuration which use available values (after all it is a inner class, there should be no problem in modifying it).

Comment: You should get a link error if you declare but not provide the default constructor (I do here with all g++ versions I've tried).